# John Wilder Tukey

Tags: probability, data-transformation, outliers, smoothing

What are the top 20 useful (but simple) analytic tools that John Tukey proposed. Especially ones you have applied and found really useful.
I will suggest:
- smoothing
- ladders of powers
- outside and far out values
......

Comment: Not only opinion-based but too broad/ a big-list type question. See the section of the help on [types of questions to avoid](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), particularly the first three items in the list of things to avoid. If it were to be edited to refocus it enough to reopen the title would in need of alteration as well as it is not indicative of the nature of the question.

Comment: @Glen_b Understood but how can It be narrowed down I think it would be a very useful reference list if it could be created.

Comment: "Reference list" type questions are not suited to the stackexchange model. See for example, the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) which comes from a blue-diamond mod (i.e. a StackExchange employee). It says things like "*we specifically forgo asking these types of questions because they are not a good fit for this type of Q&A site*" and "*the Big List breaks down the whole premise of why we created these sites in the first place*". We did have a few of that type of question early on but if they were asked now they would close.

Comment: There's something of a grey area where we can sometimes tolerate something that may become a list --  e.g. where it's not clear if there are any instances of some object ("can this ever happen?" or "does this always happen" may be legitimate sorts of questions that might lead to people posting examples or counterexamples respectively), so *some* things that end up having lists may be more-or-less okay, but in general a call like this one is simply not suited to the stackexchange model.

Comment: Ok understood why cannot allow from reading reference. But somehow a shame that cannot pool knowledge. Love to know what real experts like you a s

Comment: Many fine posts don't fit the model here. If asked here, it would be a suitable question for chat, either in Ten Fold or in its own room. If you wish to discuss the policy as applied here in crossvalidated, meta would be a good place for that (but we're not likely to be able to do more than perhaps discuss the placement of the dividing line, the policy is pretty solid).

Comment: Ok thanks for taking time explaining and for all your wonderful efforts in creating such an informative and useful resource.

Answer (score 2):

Among the achievements of the late John Tukey are the boxplot, the stem-and-leaf plot and many other methods that can be found in his exploratory data analysis book.